# Find element with most children

Tags: jquery, for-loop, children

I have a navigation bar with various nested unordered lists.
What I need to do is count the children of each UL and set a variable containing the highest counted number.

While I think I could do this using a for/while loop I'm not exactly sure how to go about it.

The script will:

1. count children of each ul, storing the lengths in an array
2. pick the longest length and store it in a new variable

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please post the HTML you want to apply the jQuery to, and what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I don't think the specific HTML is relevant as I have given the essential criteria above.
You can imagine what a series of unordered lists would look like; an answer using the selector $("ul") is fine.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: Thanks for your helpful feedback Pauly, I have outlined the technicalities of how the script will work and am asking for help on the semantics.
This post adds value to the database as it is very general and there is no similar question asked :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var arr = []; //populate the length of children into this array.
$('ul').map(function (i) {
    arr[i] = $(this).children().length;
});
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, arr); //get the max value from the array
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this does exactly what I outlined.

Answer (score 0):

IF your navigation is an 'ul' and you have to find the one have maximum children 'li' then :

```
var maximum = 0;
$('ul').each(function(){
   var height = $(this).height();
   if(height > maximum )
        maximum = maximum ;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but it works by calculating the pixel height of the ul rather than counting its children, which is not what I need.